# El método no estático necesita un destino

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, linq

he estado trabajando en una consulta vía LINQ, y me tira un error que dice que el método no estático necesita un destino y no he podido resolverlo porque simplemente no entiendo que es lo que me esta pidiendo.

En un inicio estuve tratando de almacenar el resultado de mi consulta en un VAR, sin embargo investigando encontré que era necesario definir un objeto, razón por la cual cree SesionVw, sin embargo continua tirándome el mismo error.

```
ZandwichCtx ctx = new ZandwichCtx();
            SesionVw Sesion = (from Usr in ctx.Usuario
                          join Empr in ctx.Empresa
                          on Usr.EmpresaId equals Empr.Id
                          where Usr.Email == mdl.Login.Email
                          && Usr.Password == mdl.Login.Password
                          && Empr.Status == (byte)Empresa.EStatus.Activo
                          && Usr.Status == (byte)Usuario.EStatus.Activo
                          select new SesionVw
                          {
                              EmpresaId = Empr.Id,
                              EmpresaNombre = Empr.RazonSocial,
                              UsuarioId = Usr.Id,
                              UsuarioNombre = Usr.Nombre + " " + Usr.Apellidos,
                              SucursalId = Usr.SucursalId,
                              SucursalNombre = Usr.SucursalId == 0 ? "Oficina Administrativa" :
                              ctx.Sucursal.FirstOrDefault(dbo => dbo.Id == Usr.SucursalId).Nombre,
                              UsuarioEmail = Usr.Email,
                              TipoPerfilId = Usr.TipoPerfilId
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Mi clase Usuario

```
 public class Usuario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
        public int SucursalId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public byte TipoPerfilId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public enum EStatus { Eliminado = 0, Activo = 1}
    }
```

Esta es mi clase Empresa

```
public class Empresa
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RFC { get; set; }
        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
        public string Calle { get; set; }
        public string Colonia { get; set; }
        public string Municipio { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Pais { get; set; }
        public string CP { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string SitioWeb { get; set; }
        public byte[] Logotipo { get; set; }
        public string NombreLogotipo { get; set; }
        public byte PorcientoImpuestos { get; set; }
        public int Sucursales { get; set; }
        public int Colaboradores { get; set; }
        public int Productos { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
        public decimal Renovacion { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public enum EStatus { Eliminado = 0, Activo = 1, Pendiente = 2}

    }
```

Y por ultimo mi clase SesionVw

```
public class SesionVw
    {
        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
        public string EmpresaNombre { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioNombre { get; set; }
        public int SucursalId { get; set; }
        public string SucursalNombre { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioEmail { get; set; }
        public byte TipoPerfilId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Me late que en algún punto de tu LinQ hay una referencia null. Verifica los datos por favor

Comment: Hasta donde he revisado no, pero voy a ejecutarlo directo en SQL y te comento

Comment: Pues ya verifique, directo en SQL la consulta se realiza sin problema, y como el proyecto esta en desarrollo, solo tengo 1 registro de prueba, por lo que no tengo referencias NULL

Comment: Confirma que ninguno de los valores en el `Where` no sea null.

Comment: En efecto, no se que es lo que haya pasado, esta parte estaba bien, pero mi View envía el model NULL, el problema entonces es otro.

Answer (score 1):

Noto varios puntos pero en principio veo que defines en el `select` que usas el  `FirstOrDefault()` pero accedes a la propiedad sin validar si retorna una instancia, podrias usar el `?.` para que retorne ese null en caso de no existir

```
ctx.Sucursal.FirstOrDefault(dbo => dbo.Id == Usr.SucursalId)?.Nombre
```

Tambien podrias hacer un left join con las sucursales

[Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Algo como esto

```
var Sesion = (from Usr in ctx.Usuario
              join Empr in ctx.Empresa on Usr.EmpresaId equals Empr.Id
              join Suc in ctx.Sucursal on Suc.Id equals Usr.SucursalId into gSuc
              from subSuc in gSuc.DefaultIfEmpty() 
              where Usr.Email == mdl.Login.Email
                  && Usr.Password == mdl.Login.Password
                  && Empr.Status == (byte)Empresa.EStatus.Activo
                  && Usr.Status == (byte)Usuario.EStatus.Activo
              select new SesionVw
              {
                  EmpresaId = Empr.Id,
                  EmpresaNombre = Empr.RazonSocial,
                  UsuarioId = Usr.Id,
                  UsuarioNombre = Usr.Nombre + " " + Usr.Apellidos,
                  SucursalId = Usr.SucursalId,
                  SucursalNombre = subSuc?.Nombre ?? "Oficina Administrativa" :
                  ctx.Sucursal.FirstOrDefault(dbo => ).Nombre,
                  UsuarioEmail = Usr.Email,
                  TipoPerfilId = Usr.TipoPerfilId
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

varas como se realiza el `join` con `ctx.Sucursal` para poder ver si existe la relacion

```
from subSuc in gSuc.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, al parecer el problema es otro, resulta que el View esta enviando los datos en NULL, es extraño porque en un inicio trabajaba bien, creo que tendre que volver a crear la vista.

Comment: pero cambio el mensaje del problema? porque una cosa es un fallo y otra distinta son datos en null

Comment: Eso es lo que me confunde, porque el problema es que mi model llega NULL en el POST  pero el error que me tira  es "El método no estático necesita un destino", lo extraño es que funcionaba bien esta parte, no se que paso.